# Force SDK for make and xcrun version error

Tags: xcode, macos, arm64

I am trying to compile with `make` using c++ on a 10.15 system under Xcode and Command Line Tools 12.2. It keeps wanting to use the 10.15 SDK which does not support arm64. I am thus getting `architecture not supported` errors.

My make file contains:

```
SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk
```

and the build command contains:

```
-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.0.sdk
```

Curiously:

```
xcrun --show-sdk-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk

xcrun --show-sdk-version
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'SDKVersion' in SDK '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk'
```

Any ideas? There was a clean install on Xcode 11.7 previously and then I copied 12.2 (replacing 11.7). I have verified that the SDK (v15) exists at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk` and the OSX11 SDK is also in the SDK folder.

A build for x86_64 works fine.